# Ansible get the username from the command line

Tags: ansible

In my playbooks I reference username (exclusively its "ubuntu") a lot.

Is there a built in way to say "get it from the value passed in the command line"?

I know I can do

```
ansible-playbook <task> -u <user> -K --extra-vars "user=<user>"
```

and then I can use `{{user}}` in the playbook, but it feels odd defining the user twice.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As Woodham stated, the ansible variable that represents the connecting user is

```
{{ ansible_user }} (Ansible < 2.0 was {{ ansible_ssh_user }} )
```

But you don't have to define it in the inventory file per se.

You can define it in:

**1. Your play, if you use ansible-playbook:** 
[See the manual on Playbooks](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_intro.html)

```
- name: Some play
  hosts: all
  remote_user: ubuntu
```

**2. In the inventory file:** 
[See the manual on inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html)

```
[all]
other1.example.com     ansible_user=ubuntu (Ansible < 2.0 was ansible_ssh_user)
```

**3. As you stated, on the commandline:**

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory -u ubuntu playbook.yml
```

**4. An ansible config file as a `remote_user` directive.**
[See the manual on a config file](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#remote-user)

The ansible config file can be placed in the current folder `ansible.cfg`, your homedir `.ansible.cfg` or `/etc/ansible/ansbile.cfg`.

```
[defaults]
remote_user=ubuntu
```

Comment: If you're on Ansible 2.0+, you need to use `ansible_user` instead of `ansible_ssh_user` which was [removed in 2.0](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-groups).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the standard way to do this would be define ansible_ssh_user in the inventory file and you can then reference it as {{ ansible_ssh_user }}  in the playbook.