# Using `remote_user` in `ansible_ssh_common_args` in inventory file

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

In my network there is one server (server2) that can't be accessed directly. First you have to ssh to server1 and from there to server2.

My config file has the following line:

```
remote_user = foo.bar
```

My inventory:

```
 hosts:
   server1:
     ansible_host: 10.0.0.1
   server2:
     ansible_host: 10.0.0.2
     ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q foo.bar@10.0.0.1"'
```

This works fine, but I don't want the user name to be hardcoded. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49468833/10842470) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57395833) there are examples that `remote_user` can be passed via `{{ ansible_ssh_user }}` but I can't get it to work.

What I tried:

```
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q {{ ansible_ssh_user }}@10.0.0.1"'
```

Also tried `{{ ansible_user }}` and `{{ user }}`. But when I run
`ansible server2 -m ping` I get an error

```
"The field 'ssh_common_args' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible_user' is undefined"
```

Is it possible to use user defined by `remote_user` in `ansible_ssh_common_args`?

P.S. `ansible server1 -m ping` works fine.

P.P.S. Wrote a playbook for test purposes:

```
- name: Playbook to test default user
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
  - name: Print default users
    debug:
      var: ansible_user
```

When I run `ansible-playbook test-default-user.yml --limit server1` I get

```
ok: [server1] => {
    "ansible_user": "foo.bar"
}
```

Also works with `ansible_ssh_user`, but for just `{{ user }}` I get

```
ok: [server1] => {
    "user": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

Comment: How and where exactly did you declare `ansible_ssh_user` or all other varialbles you tried ?

Comment: As far as I could understand it's defined in config file. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24121223/10842470), for example.

Comment: Added P.P.S. with a test playbook to show that `{{ ansible_user }}` is indeed defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrote this question to the Ansible mailing list and got an answer from developer.
https://groups.google.com/g/ansible-project/c/fY5lAHCEHfA

Short summary - it's not supposed to work this way. In the future there will be a special component to query plugin settings.

Update 20.06.2023 - The following works now:
`ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q {{ ansible_ssh_user }}@10.0.0.1"'`

Ansible version 2.12.10